# performSegueWithIdentifier before viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear sometimes it works and sometimes not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, nsnotificationcenter

When I call `performSegueWithIdentifier` before `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` sometimes it works and sometimes not.

**AppDelegate**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
   NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
[self abcNotif]; // the method post the notification.
}
```

**VC1:**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(theNotif:) name:@"abcNotif" object:nil];
}

-(void)theNotif:(UILocalNotification*)notif {
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"flag"]isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seg1" sender:self];
         NSLog(@"theNotif = %@", [[notif userInfo]valueForKey:@"notif1Key"]);
    }
}
```

**Logs in console**

```
awakeFromNib
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
applicationDidBecomeActive
theNotif = notif1Value
viewDidLoad
```

All is working fine although `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called before  before `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. But in some scenarios this don't work. Why is this behavior. Peoples have also asked theses kind of questions [Why doesn't performSegueWithIdentifier work inside viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308685/why-doesnt-performseguewithidentifier-work-inside-viewdidload)

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand is that UIViewController subclasses load (create) their view property lazily.  So viewDidLoad will be called after the view is loaded, but when is that?  Certainly the normal cycle of launching your app causes it at some point, adding it to the window, but you can cause it to happen earlier by making a call on the view. Try inserting [self view];  immediately before your call to performSegue.. , this will ensure the view is loaded.  Even so, it does not ensure that the view has been added to the window, and if that hasn't yet happened then I don't see how a modal can be pushed.

Comment: after calling [self view] the only change is viewDidLoad  is called before the notification. But still how performSegueWithIdentifier is working before viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear?

Comment: Well if your segue is pushing another ViewController then how can a viewController push another before it is in the stack itself?

Comment: Thats what I am asking :)